# How to not have an equation in the first line using the align environment?

Tags: vertical-alignment

Here is my code:

```
 \begin{align*}
(a-bu)e^{-\frac{1}{4}(v^2+u^2)(1+c)+\frac{1}{2}(1-c)u|v|} 
&=(a-bx-by)e^{-\frac{1}{4}((x-y)^2+(x+y)^2)(1+c)+\frac{1}{2}(1-c)(x+y)(y-x)}\\
&=(a-bx-by)e^{-(x^2+cy^2)} \\
&=f(x,y).
\end{align*}
```

I have a long equation. My question is as follows: I want to isolate the expression

```
 (a-bu)e^{-\frac{1}{4}(v^2+u^2)(1+c)+\frac{1}{2}(1-c)u|v|}
```

on the first line so that I don't have an equation on the first line and I want this expression left justified with the other lines (that have the equal sign). How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `\MoveEqLeft` from the [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \MoveEqLeft (a-bu)e^{-\frac{1}{4}(v^2+u^2)(1+c)+\frac{1}{2}(1-c)u|v|}\\
  &= (a-bx-by)e^{-\frac{1}{4}((x-y)^2+(x+y)^2)(1+c)+\frac{1}{2}(1-c)(x+y)(y-x)}\\
  &= (a-bx-by)e^{-(x^2+cy^2)}\\
  &= f(x,y).
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

giving the same output at [egreg's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154658/15874).

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

You have:

 \begin{align*}
(a-bu)e^{-\frac{1}{4}(v^2+u^2)(1+c)+\frac{1}{2}(1-c)u|v|} 
&=(a-bx-by)e^{-\frac{1}{4}((x-y)^2+(x+y)^2)(1+c)+\frac{1}{2}(1-c)(x+y)(y-x)}\\
&=(a-bx-by)e^{-(x^2+cy^2)} \\
&=f(x,y).
\end{align*}

You want to:

 \begin{align*}
&(a-bu)e^{-\frac{1}{4}(v^2+u^2)(1+c)+\frac{1}{2}(1-c)u|v|} \\
&=(a-bx-by)e^{-\frac{1}{4}((x-y)^2+(x+y)^2)(1+c)+\frac{1}{2}(1-c)(x+y)(y-x)}\\
&=(a-bx-by)e^{-(x^2+cy^2)} \\
&=f(x,y).
\end{align*}

But probably better is:


\begin{align*}
&(a-bu)e^{-\frac{1}{4}(v^2+u^2)(1+c)+\frac{1}{2}(1-c)u|v|} \\
&\qquad=(a-bx-by)e^{-\frac{1}{4}((x-y)^2+(x+y)^2)(1+c)+\frac{1}{2}(1-c)(x+y)(y-x)}\\
&\qquad=(a-bx-by)e^{-(x^2+cy^2)} \\
&\qquad=f(x,y).
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Manuel See [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154663/15874). `:)`

Comment: @Manuel No problem. `:)` It's also quite late in Denmark, so I'll go to sleep now.

Comment: I think it would be easier than putting `&\qquad=` in all following lines, as in the "better" solution above, to put a single `\qquad` in the LHS in the first line and back up over it: `\begin{align*}\qquad&\kern-2em(a-bu)...` and then just the usual `&=` in the following lines.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to enclose the first line in `\lefteqn` that gives it zero width and then add a spacing. Beware that if the formula in the first line is too long, it will spill in the margin without any warning.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Here's an example
\begin{align*}
\lefteqn{(a-bu)e^{-\frac{1}{4}(v^2+u^2)(1+c)+\frac{1}{2}(1-c)u|v|}}
  \qquad\\
&=(a-bx-by)e^{-\frac{1}{4}((x-y)^2+(x+y)^2)(1+c)+\frac{1}{2}(1-c)(x+y)(y-x)}\\
&=(a-bx-by)e^{-(x^2+cy^2)} \\
&=f(x,y).
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Change `\qquad` to any other spacing you'd like; I suggest not remove this spacing, because it will give more clues to the readers for understanding what's going on. In a chain of equalities, the initial expression should always start at the left of the derived expressions.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What about this? Do you like it? Note the use of `\phantom`, suggested by @Harish.

```
\begin{multline*}
(a-bu)e^{-\frac{1}{4}(v^2+u^2)(1+c)+\frac{1}{2}(1-c)u|v|} =\\
(a-bx-by)e^{-\frac{1}{4}((x-y)^2+(x+y)^2)(1+c)+\frac{1}{2}(1-c)(x+y)(y-x)}=\\
(a-bx-by)e^{-(x^2+cy^2)} = f(x,y).
\end{multline*} 

\begin{align*}  %% note the use of \phantom, suggested by Harish
&\phantom{{}={}} (a-bu)e^{-\frac{1}{4}(v^2+u^2)(1+c)+\frac{1}{2}(1-c)u|v|} \\
&=(a-bx-by)e^{-\frac{1}{4}((x-y)^2+(x+y)^2)(1+c)+\frac{1}{2}(1-c)(x+y)(y-x)}\\
&=(a-bx-by)e^{-(x^2+cy^2)} \\
&=f(x,y).
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Comment: @SvendTveskæg, I agree. But we try to satisfy his/her wishes. lol

Answer (score 0):

A beautiful and useful approach!

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}% change this line back to \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
It is the Code Mocker's equation
\begin{multline*}
    \hspace{3cm} (a-bu)e^{-\frac{1}{4}(v^2+u^2)(1+c)+\frac{1}{2}(1-c)u|v|}\\
    \!
    \begin{aligned}
            &=(a-bx-by)e^{-\frac{1}{4}((x-y)^2+(x+y)^2)(1+c)+\frac{1}{2}(1-c)(x+y)(y-x)}\\
            &=(a-bx-by)e^{-(x^2+cy^2)} \\
            &=f(x,y)
    \end{aligned}
\end{multline*}
where $f(x,y)$ is nothing.
\end{document}
```

[image]