# aligning an equation to the left

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have the following equation:

```
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{4}\left[\frac{\partial{(u^n+u^*)(u^n+u^*)}}{\partial{x}}\right]_p 
&=\nonumber\\
\dfrac{u_{fe}\dfrac{\dfrac{u_{i,j,k}^n+u_{i,j,k}^{*}}{2}+
\dfrac{u_{i+1,j,k}^n+u_{i+1,j,k}^{*}}{2}}{2}-u_{fw}
\dfrac{\dfrac{u_{i,j,k}^n+u_{i,j,k}^{*}}{2}
+\dfrac{u_{i-1,j,k}^n+u_{i-1,j,k}^{*}}{2}}{2}}{dx_i + dx_{i+1}}\quad ,
\end{align}
```

which give me this[image]

Now, I am wondering how I can align it to the left side? I tried eqnarray, aligned and flalign, but they did not help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154663/14757

Answer (score 2):

I would do this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{4}\biggl[\frac{\partial{(u^n+u^*)(u^n+u^*)}}{\partial{x}}\biggr]_p
&=\dfrac{u_{fe}\biggl(\!\!\dfrac{A+B}
{2}\biggr)-u_{fw}
\biggl(\!\!\dfrac{A + C}{2}\biggr)}{dx_i + dx_{i+1}}
\shortintertext{where}
  A &= \frac{u_{i,j,k}^n+u_{i,j,k}^{*}}{2}, \notag\\
  B &= \frac{u_{i+1,j,k}^n+u_{i+1,j,k}^{*}}{2}, \notag\\
  C &= \frac{u_{i-1,j,k}^n+u_{i-1,j,k}^{*}}{2}. \notag
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, it is better to use `\biggl` and `\biggr` constructs over `\left` and `\right`.

Answer (score 2):

Environment `multline` could help:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
\frac{1}{4}\left[\frac{\partial{(u^n+u^*)(u^n+u^*)}}{\partial{x}}\right]_p
=\\
\dfrac{u_{fe}\dfrac{\dfrac{u_{i,j,k}^n+u_{i,j,k}^{*}}{2}+
\dfrac{u_{i+1,j,k}^n+u_{i+1,j,k}^{*}}{2}}{2}-u_{fw}
\dfrac{\dfrac{u_{i,j,k}^n+u_{i,j,k}^{*}}{2}
+\dfrac{u_{i-1,j,k}^n+u_{i-1,j,k}^{*}}{2}}{2}}{dx_i + dx_{i+1}}\quad ,
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]